# theano-scan: how outputs_info with placeholder feed as input

Tags: python, theano

i am confused about outputs_info of scan in theano. below is an example of scan which computes A**k:

```
k = T.iscalar("k")
A = T.vector("A")
def inner_fct(prior_result, B):
    return prior_result * B
# Symbolic description of the result
result, updates = theano.scan(fn=inner_fct,
                            outputs_info=T.ones_like(A),
                            non_sequences=A, n_steps=k)
# Scan has provided us with A ** 1 through A ** k.  Keep only the last
# value. Scan notices this and does not waste memory saving them.
final_result = result[-1]
power = theano.function(inputs=[A, k], outputs=final_result,
                      updates=updates)
print(power(range(10), 2))
```

i make a little change as below:

```
k = T.iscalar("k")
A = T.vector("A")
def inner_fct(prior_result, B):
    return B, B, prior_result * B   #!! change return of inner_fct
#!! change scan as below
[B1, B2, result], updates = theano.scan(fn=inner_fct,
                            outputs_info=[None, None, T.ones_like(A)],
                            non_sequences=A, n_steps=k)
final_result = result[-1]
power = theano.function(inputs=[A, k], outputs=final_result,
                      updates=updates)
print(power(range(10), 2))
```

it still get the same result as the original.  and when i change outpus_info=[None, T.ones_like(A), None] or ouputs_info=[T.ones_like(A), None, None], it still get the same result. 
T.ones_like(A) will serve as the initial of prior_result in inner_fct, so can i assume that theano will find an not None one as the initial of prior_result?

how exactly theano choose initials in outputs_info as input?

```
k = T.iscalar("k")
A = T.vector("A")
def inner_fct(prior_result, B):
    return B, prior_result*B, prior_result * B   #!! change return of inner_fct
#!! change scan as below
[B1, B2, result], updates = theano.scan(fn=inner_fct,
                            outputs_info=[None, None, T.ones_like(A)],
                            non_sequences=A, n_steps=k)
power = theano.function(inputs=[A, k], outputs=[B2,result],
                      updates=updates)
print(power(range(10), 2))
```

the second param in outputs_info is None, which means the second output of inner_fct is not recurrent, but `print(power(range(10), 2))` shows that `B2` are same as `result`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`outputs_info` works just as [the documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html#theano.scan) says it works.

In particular,

> outputs_info is the list of Theano variables or dictionaries
>   describing the initial state of the outputs computed recurrently.

and,

> If you provide a None instead of a variable or a empty dictionary scan
>   assumes that you will not use any taps for this output (like for
>   example in case of a map)

The number of elements in the `outputs_info` list should match the number of values returned by the `scan` step function. In your first example, the step function returns a single value so the `outputs_info` should (and does) contain a single element. In your second example the step function returns three values so the `outputs_info` should (and does) contain three elements.

For each value in `outputs_info`, if it is `None` then you are saying that the value is not recurrent (outputs in this position are not made available to later iterations). A non-`None` `outputs_info` value indicates that the step output in that position *is* recurrent and the value provided is the initial value to be be passed to the step function in the first step; subsequent steps receive the output from the previous step.

So `scan` is not doing some clever magic to automatically figure out which element contains the initial value. You've simply told Theano to do something specific in the second example, the step function returns two non-recurrent values (hence the two `None`s) followed by one recurrent value (hence the initial value in the third position).

In the third example (added in a question edit), there is still only one recurrent output from the step function (the third). It is the `outputs_info` values that determines which outputs are recurrent and, in the third example, there is only one non-`None` `outputs_info` value. The `B2` function output and the `result` function output are the same because they have identical computation expressions: `prior_result*B`. It doesn't matter which of these two values is iterated, they remain identical throughout.

Comment: i still have a little confusion.   if change the output of inner_fct as `return B, prior_result*B, prior_result * B` , and the outputs_info as usual.  then we can see that `result` is same as `B2` after run `power`, which means `B2` is recurrent. but the second of outputs_info is None which means `B2` is not recurrent,  anything i misunderstood?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Could you edit your question to include the code for this additional variation?

Comment: sorry i did not make it clearly.   i edit my question by adding a third code block.  the second of outputs_info is None,  but the result shows that `B2` is same as `result`